# Transactions that led to the discovery of TheDAO hacker

Tags: transactions, security, bitcoin, the-dao

What are the transactions that led to the [discovery of the apparent hacker of TheDAO](https://www.forbes.com/sites/laurashin/2022/02/22/exclusive-austrian-programmer-and-ex-crypto-ceo-likely-stole-11-billion-of-ether/)?

What are the primary transactions across the Ethereum, Bitcoin, and Grin blockchains?